# Wrong tooltip for vote buttons on questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

Due to an unknown mistake, the tooltips for the vote buttons now read

> Downvote this question if you find it unclear or not useful

and

> Upvote this question if you find it clear and useful

The original and correct tooltips were

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

and

> This question does not show any research effort; it is not useful or unclear

respectively.

Somehow the *shows research effort / does not show any research effort* part was lost. However, this part is essential on Chemistry Stackexchange (and probably most other Stackexchange sites).

Such tooltips on frequently used buttons might not be important for regular users of this site who know how most things are supposed to work. However, many new users have difficulties to see and understand some basic principles of this site, as we can especially see when looking at the many homework questions that do not show any research effort.

The tooltips alone will not solve such problems; however, a little guidance here and there might help us to steer more new users in the right direction. Removing this tooltip was a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Huh, I wonder why it was changed in this interface modification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltips have been rolled back, see [this answer on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349800).

The tooltips are now

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

and

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

again.